# cascade dropdown using database in javaEE

Tags: javascript, oracle, jsp, jakarta-ee, cascadingdropdown

i am trouble with using cascade dropdown
im using **JAVA EE** and **oracle** database and i have to use **javascript**.

i heard about javascript can do this but im still trouble with..